# Nail in sidewall.

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image: Nail]

Recently just got this nail in my tire. Was told by my local firestone that it’s too close to the sidewall. I just got the tire so I’m not looking to throw away a perfectly good tire on a technicality. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Some tire shops will patch it some will not, I would have it patched.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This is a prime candidate for a plug which you can do at home.

Comment: I'm not overwhelmed by the amount of remaining tread. I'd avoid both issues and replace the tire.

Answer (score 1):

For your safety and others just replace the tire...

IMHO it is outside the safe repair area but, as you have been told by your local firestone the same thing you can go to another dealer for another opinion.

Answer (score -1):

A patch wall repair along with the inclined nozzle for cauterizing would cost you $40. A brand new tire from the dealer $117 to $130 from a genuine dealer. So the debate is $60 to $80 difference.

Your call now.

Comment: So, you equate the value of your life to be $60 ...

Comment: It's his call, old friend.

Comment: Except the OP isn't driving around in a vacuum - there's other road users, pedestrians etc to consider.